# doing weighted avg with sumproduct

Tags: excel, vba

I have looked at other questions with this topic but the code still does not work for me. I want to calculate the weighted mean by doing sumproduct of two columns and normalizing it to the sum of one column.

```
Sub compute()
With Worksheet
.Range("AT2").Value = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(.Range("AQ"),.Range("AR"))/SUMPRODUCT(.Range("AQ"))")
End With
End Sub
```

OR

```
Sub compute()
.Range("AT2").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SUMPRODUCT((.Range("AQ"), .Range("AR"))/Application.WorksheetFunction.SUM(.Range("AQ"))
End Sub
```

Comment: You are using `.` in front of the `Range(...` this indicates that it is part of a With block, but no with block is present.  Also in the second you have one to many `(`  on the `Application.WorksheetFunction.SUMPRODUCT((...`

Comment: Thanks, this worked Range("AT2").Value = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(AQ2:AQ152,AR2:AR152)/SUM(AQ2:AQ152)")